# try - except struggle

Tags: python, try-catch, except

I am trying to stop this program if the number the person enters is not 4 numbers long, using the try-except structure. I don't really get why it skips the except block if I enter a 2 or 3 digit number for example. All help appreciated.

```
guess = int(input('Guess a 4 digit number:\n'))
guesslist = [int(x) for x in (str(guess))]
x = 0
y = 0

try:
    print(len(str(guess)))
    len(str(guess)) == 4

except:
    print('please enter a 4 digit number')
    quit()

print('past')
```

Comment: a `try` is not an `if`. The `except` triggers only when an `Error` is thrown inside the `try`; not if a test fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `try`/`except` syntax catches exceptions (aka errors).  If there are no errors thrown by the code in a `try` clause, the `except` clause is skipped. You don't have any obvious errors in your `try` clause.

From the [`try`/`except` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html):

> First, the try clause (the statement(s) between the try and except keywords) is executed.
>   If no exception occurs, the except clause is skipped and execution of the try statement is finished.

Use `if`/`then` conditional syntax instead:

```
if len(str(guess)) == 4:
    print(len(str(guess)))
else:
    print('please enter a 4 digit number')
    quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an `assert` to `len(str(guess)) == 4` so it is `assert len(str(guess)) == 4`.

The reason why is that just having `len(str(guess)) == 4` is useless - that is run but you haven't told Python to do anything with the result. If you `assert`, it basically means verify the next code is true, otherwise throw an exception.

Comment: You shouldn't really use assert statements for this kind of thing, as they are for debugging: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-assert-statement

Answer (score 0):

You need to raise an exception in order to trigger the except. Try it like this:

```
guess = int(input('Guess a 4 digit number:\n'))
guesslist = [int(x) for x in (str(guess))]
x = 0
y = 0
try:
    print(len(str(guess)))
    if(len(str(guess)) != 4):
        raise Exception("Invalud number")

except:
    print('please enter a 4 digit number')
    quit()

print('past')
```